# Remove boolean colums with false

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

What is the most efficient way to remove a row where all boolean columns are false?

This works for 1 column. How could I extend it for a list of columns:

```
cols_to_drop_if_all_are_false = ['var1', 'var2','var3']
df = df.loc[df.var1, :]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use , `df.all()` in `axis=1` then invert (`~`)

```
df[~df[cols_to_drop_if_all_are_false].all(1)]
```